# Strongly typed web api route endpoints in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

So I have two separate projects (one Web Api 2 and one MVC) like this diagram: [image]

The MVC has controllers and a service layer. The services from the MVC app call to the web api controllers. For example:

```
await _service.GetGiftCards("/api/GiftCards/ViewAllByUser", email);
```

The Web Api controllers have their routes defined like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/giftcards")]
[Route("ViewAllByUser")]
    public async Task<List<GiftCard>> GetGiftCardsForUser(string email){}
```

So to define the endpoint route in the MVC app I simply pass a string like "/api/GiftCards/ViewAllByUser" above.

My question is, is there a better way to sort of "strongly type" the endpoints of the Web Api routes that are defined so I can do something like?:

```
await _service.GetGiftCards(GiftCardController.ViewAllByUser, email);
```

I guess at a minimum I could always just store the endpoint strings in a static class like so, so they at least can all be updated in one place:

```
public static class ApiEndpoints(){
     public string GetAllGiftCards = "api/GiftCards/ViewAllByUser";
}
```

but I'm looking to know if there are better ways or other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there are reason you're explicitly specifying routes rather than relying on conventions?

Comment: The Web API controllers will be used from several external apps (web, mobile, etc.) and will encapsulate data access and business logic, so I was naming them more like descriptive method names, but I can see the use in relying on conventions in most instances instead. But regardless of what my route name is, I still want to be able to strongly reference it in order to use it.

Comment: If you want a strongly-typed representation of a uniform resource locator, well, [there's a type for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx). Maybe keep a map of actions to these guys? You're going to end up building them out of strings at some point, though, because that's what URLs are.

Comment: @DanJ Yeah, I see your point that it will most likely need to be a string at some point; but if there was some way that I could sort of map between the Web API project and MVC project that would be good. That way if someone updates the route name in the Web API project, as long as the MVC project is using this "mapping", the string endpoint won't have to manually be updated there as well.

Comment: That's a reasonable desire. What you're proposing sounds very much like WCF, with its strongly-typed contracts. That's a trade-off you make for the interoperability of Web API (I can see you have multiple clients of different types). It's possible a mixed approach might serve, if having automatic parity between the MVC app and the service is that important.

Answer (score 3):

API routes shouldn't specify actions. You want your routes to be logical paths to a record or group of records. Example, in your case the route should look something like this:

```
GET
api/giftcards/{userID:int:min(1)}
```

You want to be able to walk up the url basically and get what you would expect. In the case of the example route you would get gift cards based on the user id. If you were to take off the user id page and just call api/giftcards you would expect to get all gift cards by all users. I'm using an ID here but you would do the same with email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take that into account as a better naming standard as it is a good idea. However, that still doesn't resolve my issue of how I can "strongly" reference that route in my MVC project so I don't have to manually pass the url as a string. Any ideas on that?

Comment: It looks like you already have the best way of doing that. Use constant paths inside of nested classes. So basically you have an AppConstants class with a static class inside of it called APIRoutes then static constant strings with your api paths. Then to call it you would use it just like you are in your question: (AppConstants.APIRoutes.Giftcards, email)

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try with 'ActionName'  Attribute on action like this :

```
 [ActionName("SelectAll")]
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
        {
       ...
        }
```

calling this action name like:

```
$("#getdata").click(function () {
  var options = {};
  options.url = "/api/customer/SelectAll";
  options.type = "GET";
  ...
  ...
  $.ajax(options);
});
```

note: 'getdata' is id of control which click event will be fired and calling 'api method' and getdata from api

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a library](https://github.com/zijianhuang/webapiclientgen) that may be what you're looking for.

Although I like static strings so you don't always have to show future developers on your team how to use said library when updates are needed on the clients.